# How do I access the nested container within a custom resolver?

Tags: structuremap, automapper

I'm using a nested container to provide access to contextual items, as outlined [here](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2010/04/28/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-contextual-controller-injection.aspx).

In Application_Start, I'm creating my maps in a similar manor as:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MyObject, MyMappedObject>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Url, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<MyResolver>());


public class MyResolver<MyObject, string> {
  protected override string ResolveCore(MyObject source) {
    var urlHelper = ObjectFactory.Container.GetNestedContainer().GetInstance<UrlHelper>();
    return urlHelper.GetMyUrl(source);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this only gets access to the container, not the nested container.  Is it possible to access contextual items in a custom resolver?  If so, is there a nice way of doing so with StructureMap?

As a side note, I am able to get to the nested container within the custom resolver by the HttpContext.Current.Items collection.  This seems like an undesirable method to me, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always just put a wrapper around the item that was stuffed into HttpContext.Items.

```
public static class Current
{
  public static IContainer Container
 {     //Throw exception if the item isn't there 
   return (IContainer)HttpContext.Items[yourKey];   
 }
}
```

Not very pretty, but unless you go with a framework that really embraces IOC, I haven't found a nice way to do it.

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of what I was trying to avoid, if possible :)  Not sure if there is an alternative, though